# No cookies for specific website

Tags: python, sqlite, firefox, cookies

I am [reading Firefox cookies via Python](https://github.com/dotancohen/pytility/blob/master/read-firefox-cookies.py) in order to access some websites. One particular website does not seems to have any cookies stored in the normal Firefox `cookies.sqlite` database, even though I can plainly see that cookies are being sent and received from that host when I open the pages in Firefox. Also, the login feature works in Firefox, that is, I am currently logged into the site and viewing my personal account there.

Here is an example of how one can read the cookies in Firefox via `sqlite`:

```
$ sqlite3 /home/dotancohen/.mozilla/firefox/lixn8e40.default/cookies.sqlite
SQLite version 3.8.11.1 2015-07-29 20:00:57
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> SELECT count(*) FROM moz_cookies WHERE host LIKE '%stack%';
39
```

We see that I have 39 cookies for hosts with the word `stack` in the hostname. However, for [this particular site](https://mcatrack.com) I do not seem to have any cookies in the sqlite file:

```
sqlite> SELECT count(*) FROM moz_cookies WHERE host LIKE '%mcatrack%';
0
```

That said, when I do request a page via Firefox the browser does in fact send a cookie and I see that I'm logged into my account:

```
Host: mcatrack.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: https://mcatrack.com/users/sign_in
Cookie: _mcatrack_session=bVhx<FOOBARFOOBARFOOBAR>ae8
Connection: keep-alive
If-None-Match: "dfbd28a1a1e6585154d340560c55ef42"
```

Where is that cookie stored?

**Note that the issue does not seems to be because the site in question is using HTTPS, as I can see my Gmail cookies in the Sqlite database as well.**

Answer (score 0):

**Not all cookies are written to the `cookies.sqlite` file.** Supposedly for performance reasons, some cookies are held in memory only, but even those cookies are written to `sessionstore-backups/recovery.js` in case of crash. ‎Thus, we can open that file, parse the JSON, and get those cookies:

```
sessions_file = os.path.join(profile_folder, 'sessionstore-backups/recovery.js')
sessions_input = open(sessions_file, 'r')
sessions_data = json.loads(sessions_input.read())

for win in sessions_data['windows']:
    for item in win['cookies']:
        # Item Fields: host, path, name, value
        print('Host: ' + str(item['host']))
```

It appears that in addition to the fields `host, path, name, value` there is also sometimes a field `httponly` which is always `True` when it exists. I suspect that there should be an additional optional field `secure` as well but I've yet to come across it in testing.